# Exec and List Comprehension doesn't work fine?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exec, list-comprehension

I'm a Japanese Python newbie.
When I hacked a Python code, I found a funny phenomenon/
My aim is to investigate the hehaviour of exec function, list comprehension, and scope.

The following code runs successfully.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# test1.py

exec ('''
book = {"Apple":[120,15], "Orange":[95,32], "Banana":[60,71]}
print("↓↓globals()↓↓")
print(globals())
print()
print("↓↓locals()↓↓")
print(locals())
print()

print("↓↓One-Values↓↓")
print(book["Apple"])
print()

keys = [x for x in list(book.keys())]
print("↓↓All-Keys↓↓")
print(keys)
print()

values = [book[x] for x in list(book.keys())]
print("↓↓All-Values↓↓")
print(values)
''')
```

The result is as I had expected:

```
$ test1.py
↓↓globals()↓↓
{'__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, '__doc__': None, '__cached__': None, '__package__': None, '__loader__': <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f7bc7387588>, 'builtins': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', 'book': {'Banana': [60, 71], 'Orange': [95, 32], 'Apple': [120, 15]}, '__file__': './test1.py', '__spec__': None}

↓↓locals()↓↓
{'__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, '__doc__': None, '__cached__': None, '__package__': None, '__loader__': <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f7bc7387588>, 'builtins': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', 'book': {'Banana': [60, 71], 'Orange': [95, 32], 'Apple': [120, 15]}, '__file__': './test1.py', '__spec__': None}

↓↓One-Values↓↓
[120, 15]

↓↓All-Keys↓↓
['Banana', 'Orange', 'Apple']

↓↓All-Values↓↓
[[60, 71], [95, 32], [120, 15]]
```

The dictionary is looked up successfully.

```
print(book["Apple"])
===>
[120, 15]
```

The first list comprehension is evaluated successfully too.

```
keys = [x for x in list(book.keys())]
===>
['Orange', 'Apple', 'Banana']
```

The second list comprehension is evaluated suuessfully too.

```
values = [book[x] for x in list(book.keys())]
===>
[[60, 71], [95, 32], [120, 15]]
```

But when I tried to invoke exec function from the user-defined function:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# test2.py

def exec_test(s):
    exec(s)

exec_test ('''
book = {"Apple":[120,15], "Orange":[95,32], "Banana":[60,71]}
print("↓↓globals()↓↓")
print(globals())
print()
print("↓↓locals()↓↓")
print(locals())
print()

print("↓↓One-Values↓↓")
print(book["Apple"])
print()

keys = [x for x in list(book.keys())]
print("↓↓All-Keys↓↓")
print(keys)
print()

values = [book[x] for x in list(book.keys())]
print("↓↓All-Values↓↓")
print(values)
''')
```

The result differs:

```
$ test2.py
↓↓globals()↓↓
{'__cached__': None, '__package__': None, '__file__': './test2.py', '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, 'exec_test': <function exec_test at 0x7f7aaa88c2f0>, '__loader__': <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f7aaa927588>, '__doc__': None, '__spec__': None, 'builtins': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__'}

↓↓locals()↓↓
{'book': {'Orange': [95, 32], 'Apple': [120, 15], 'Banana': [60, 71]}, 's': '\nbook = {"Apple":[120,15], "Orange":[95,32], "Banana":[60,71]}\nprint("↓↓globals()↓↓")\nprint(globals())\nprint()\nprint("↓↓locals()↓↓")\nprint(locals())\nprint()\n\nprint("↓↓One-Values↓↓")\nprint(book["Apple"])\nprint()\n\nkeys = [x for x in list(book.keys())]\nprint("↓↓All-Keys↓↓")\nprint(keys)\nprint()\n\nvalues = [book[x] for x in list(book.keys())]\nprint("↓↓All-Values↓↓")\nprint(values)\n'}

↓↓One-Values↓↓
[120, 15]

↓↓All-Keys↓↓
['Orange', 'Apple', 'Banana']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test2.py", line 33, in <module>
    ''')
  File "./test2.py", line 10, in exec_test
    exec(s)
  File "<string>", line 19, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 19, in <listcomp>
NameError: name 'book' is not defined
```

The dictionary is looked up successfully.

```
print(book["Apple"])
===>
[120, 15]
```

The first list comprehension is evaluated successfully too.

```
keys = [x for x in list(book.keys())]
===>
['Orange', 'Apple', 'Banana']
```

**But the second list comprehension is evaluated failed because of NameError.**

```
values = [book[x] for x in list(book.keys())]
===>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test2.py", line 33, in <module>
    ''')
  File "./test2.py", line 10, in exec_test
    exec(s)
  File "<string>", line 19, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 19, in <listcomp>
NameError: name 'book' is not defined
```

Why?

My questions are as below:

**Q1: why global `book` disappeared?**

if you wrote:

```
exec("""
hash = {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2",...}
""")
```

The hash is in both `globals()` and `locals()`.

but if you wrote:

```
def do_exec(s) {
  exec(s)

do_exec("""
hash = {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2",...}
""")
```

The hash is only in `locals()`.

Why?

**Q2: why `book[x]` cannot find `book` while `book.keys()` could find it?**

In test1.py, both list comprehension works fine.

```
keys = [x for x in list(book.keys())]

values = [book[x] for x in list(book.keys())]
```

But In test2.py, only the second list comprehension turns NameError.

I think the reason is `book` is only local in test2.py. and the list comprehension makes its own scope so the name `book` was not found.

But then, why the first list comprehension ran safely?
In other words, why `book.keys()` method call could find the name `book`?

These are my questions.
Please give me any suggestions.
Thank you very much in advance!

My environment:

```
$ python3 -V
Python 3.5.2

$ uname -a
Linux DESKTOP-AHPUUO5 4.4.0-43-Microsoft #1-Microsoft Wed Dec 31 14:42:53 PST 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Probably has something to do with the fact that the actual `exec` statement is inside the function, making things local.

Comment: @Pythonista something weird is going on though, since _all_ the code is local, no variables should be out of the scope. `book` was defined locally, and should be accessible locally. Unless part of the code is somehow being run in the global scope.